# Store spase array SQLite3

Tags: python, c++, sqlite, blob

1. I have a sparse array `float A[1000000]` which I want to store as an attribute in a table column. I wanted to compress this array in order to store it.
   Every Row is compose of the 3 attributes: 
   `<Att1 string,Att2 string,Sparce Array>`
2. The Sparse array must be retrieved from the table and then decompressed.

---

- How Can I store the sparse matrix in the last column?
- Can I compress it by using a library from python or any other language then store it in the cell?
- Do you have an idea on how I can represent it?

---

Comment: Why not having a table for it, like `A (idx int, value float)`?

Comment: And every row is a value? I didn't understand well

Comment: Yes, every row is a value. Then you don't need to compress anything and can read entries straight from the database. (That, of course, depends on how you're going to use the data)

Comment: I modified the question @bereal in fact the whole array must be stored in a single cell as an Attribute. Every row is composed for 3 attribute the 3rd attribute will be  the sparse array

Comment: So, apply the [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) to store the array into a separate table and make a 1-N reference from the first table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you're going to use the data, but from the design point of view I suggest applying the [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and store the sparse array into the second table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE record (id INT, attr1 TEXT, attr2 TEXT);
CREATE TABLE sparse_arr (record_id INT, idx INT, value FLOAT);
```

Comment: my problem is that The sparse_array wil have sometimes 10,000,000 values. Do you think it's a good way to store it? can't I find a way to compress it? isn't that better?

Comment: @HaniGoc do you mean, 10 million used values or including the zeros?

Comment: oh including the Zeros: 
example V = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1.5,0,0,0,...,0,0,0,0.6,0,...,0,0,0,0,0] dimenstion = 10000000

Comment: @HaniGoc then you just don't store the zeros in the DB, that's the point.

Comment: oh ok I get it I get it!! well Yes I can do that that's Since it's a sparse matrix so i don't have a lot of non zero values. I get It now it's much simpler

Comment: one last comment Please. If I have many rows in table records. Would make the problem more complex? And since for every row I have to add a new table for the sparse matrix. Do u have an idea on how much the complexity might increase?

Comment: No, you don't need to add the table for each row. I fixed the schema, so that's cleaner. You only need to keep reference to the record for each array item (`record_id`). The question of performance depends on the numbers, and what operations you're going to use. As far as I know, sqlite is not particularly good in storing huge volumes of data, but if we're speaking of thousands, that's ok. Certainly, you will need to add indices.

Comment: One possible enhancement would be adding an index on sparse_arr(record_id,idx) so looking up a specific element of the sparse array would be quick.